# How to get Galleria working with images loaded via jQuery's load() function

Tags: jquery, load, galleria

I'm using Galleria 1.2.7 and jQuery 1.7.1 for a photography site. I have 3 sets of photos which I want Galleria to show so I have 3 links on the page. I want to load them into the index page using load().

My code is:

```
    <div id="galleria"></div>

<ul id="nav">
  <li><a href="gallery1.html">Gallery 1</a></li>
  <li><a href="gallery2.html">Gallery 2</a></li>
  <li><a href="gallery3.html">Gallery 3</a></li>
</ul>

<script> 

        $(document).ready(function(){
            Galleria.loadTheme('galleria/themes/folio/galleria.folio.min.js');

             $('#nav a')
                .click(function(){
                    $('#galleria').load(this.href, function(){
                        $('#galleria').galleria();
                    });
                    return false;
                });
        });


</script>
```

This works when I click one of the links but when a second link is clicked it stops working. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What does `gallery1.html` look like?

Answer (score 0):

u tried handle postback ?

```
postbackFunction();

if (Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().get_isInAsyncPostBack()){
    postbackFunction();
});

function postbackFunction(){
        $(document).ready(function(){
            Galleria.loadTheme('galleria/themes/folio/galleria.folio.min.js');
         $('#nav a')
            .click(function(){
                $('#galleria').load(this.href, function(){
                    $('#galleria').galleria();
                });
                return false;
            });
    });
}
```